# Prove that the sequence given by its general term $\frac{\sqrt{n^2+1}-n}{\sqrt{n+3}+2n}$ is strictly decreasing.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Prove that the sequence given by its general term:

$$\frac{\sqrt{n^2+1}-n}{\sqrt{n+3}+2n}$$

is strictly decreasing.

$a_n>a_{n+1} \Leftrightarrow \frac{\sqrt{n^2+1}-n}{\sqrt{n+3}+2n}>\frac{\sqrt{(n+1)^2+1}-(n+1)}{\sqrt{(n+1)+3}+2(n+1)}$

Is there some kind of trick to apply in these sorts of problems or do I have to solve this by sheer algebraic manipulation? If I subtract $\frac{\sqrt{(n+1)^2+1}-(n+1)}{\sqrt{(n+1)+3}+2(n+1)}$ from both sides I'll end up with something really ugly so I'm wondering if there's a better way.

Answer (score 6):

#### Hint:

$$a_n=\frac{\sqrt{n^2+1}-n}{\sqrt{n+3}+2n}=\frac{(\sqrt{n^2+1}-n)(\sqrt{n^2+1}+n)}{(\sqrt{n+3}+2n)(\sqrt{n^2+1}+n)}=\frac1{(\sqrt{n+3}+2n)(\sqrt{n^2+1}+n)}$$

Comment: Beat me by 12s... +1

Comment: I'm sorry about the late response...
I understand that $a_{n+1}=\frac{1}{{(\sqrt{n+4}+2n+2)}{(\sqrt{n^2+2n+2}+n+1})}$ so $a_{n+1}$ will have a greater denominator so it'll be smaller than $a_n$, but do I still need to do some algebra to prove it, or do I leave it like that?